# Know users of particular iOS app version

Tags: ios

Is there a way to know the number of users who are still using a particular ios application version?

Comment: You need to do some user track before in your app.

Comment: [have you heard about Google Analytics?](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create one webservice which will accept UDID of user's device as well as the Application version. And you can get the reports from that.

For more report of user app you can integrate Flurry analytics to your app.